# Raspberry Pi Audio - Can not get 5.1 Surround Sound Audio to output to HDMI

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, hdmi, omxplayer

I have an applications where I need to do the following on a Raspberry Pi (3, 4, and/or Zero) running the latest version of Raspberry Pi OS:

1. Play an AC3 file with 5.1 audio over HDMI.
2. Play an MP3 or WAV file to a specific speaker in the 5.1 audio over HDMI.

I am currently using OMXPLAYER and have tried some of the Pulse Audio and APlayer approaches I found in other places but no luck so far.  The problem is that I can not get the output to the HDMI port to be 5.1 as it keeps downmixinpg it to 2 channel audio.

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: How is this programming related?

Comment: I think what @KenWhite is trying to say is that SO is sadly not the platform for this question. You might want to try https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok, I will move it there.

Comment: Moved to [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/124109/raspberry-pi-audio-can-not-get-5-1-surround-sound-audio-to-output-to-hdmi) so that it could be answered in the proper group.